# Is there a way to parse a XML according to its attributes?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse my xml using minidom.parse but the program crushes when debugger reaches line  `xmldoc = minidom.parse(self)`

Here is what have I tried:

```
attribValList = list()
xmldoc = minidom.parse(path)
equipments = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName(xmldoc , elementName)
equipNames = equipments.getElementsByTagName(xmldoc , attributeKey)
for item in equipNames:
    attribValList.append(item.value)

return attribValList
```

Maybe my XML is too specific for minidom. Here is how it looks like:

```
<TestSystem id="...">
    <Port>58</Port>
    <TestSystemEquipment>
        <Equipment type="BCAFC">
            <Name>System1</Name>
            <DU-Junctions>
                ...
            </DU-Junctions>
        </Equipment>
```

Basically I need to get for each `Equipment` its name and write the names into a list.

Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91XMB.png)

Comment: `parse` expects a file path, `parseString` on the other hand expects a string, what are you passing in `self`?

Comment: @DirtyBit yeahh I see, my bad. Thanks

Comment: Okay, does that mean anything? were you able to solve it?

Comment: @DirtyBit unfortunately no. I get a huge object and when the debugger comes to line equipments = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName(self, elementName) then it crashes

Comment: What exactly is the "huge object"? When the program crashes, is there an error message and stack trace? How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: @mzjn I have attached an image. Can you check please. I was supposing that I'll get a list with all attributes somehow

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I can't reproduce a problem by looking at an image. Please provide a [mcve].